# Untoggle all figure toolbar buttons

Tags: matlab, user-interface, toolbar

I want to add a new toggle button to the figure toolbar. When it is clicked, I want to "untoggle" any other buttons that were toggled. E.g, if the "rotation" or "zoom" toggle buttons were pressed, I want to untoggle them and their effect.
Simply getting all their handles does not work, as this does not deactivate their effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first find all of the children of toolbar. You can do it by the following command (Assuming that `currentToggleButton` is a handle to current toggle button):

```
 get( get(currentToggleButton,'Parent'),'Children');
```

Then do the following:

```
  set(children,'State','off');
```

Of course, you need to return the state of your current button to `on`.

```
  set(currentToggleButton,'State','on');
```

By the way, if you are using GUIDE, you can add `zoom`,`rotate` and `pan` as pre-defined tools. In that case, Matlab will handle the toggling automatically.

---

In order to turn off the effect of zooming/pan/rotation, you can do:

```
 zoom('off')
 pan('off')
 rotate3d('off')
```

or you can use another syntax version (as @Eitan also mentions)

```
 zoom off
 pan off
 rotate3d off
```

Comment: Thanks :) but this won't do - Simply setting their state to "off" does not make their effect stop. I.e, if I click the rotate button and then run your code, indeed, it will render as untoggled, but when I'll drag my mouse it will still rotate my plots.

Comment: @noam, in this case you should do the command `rotate('off')`, or `zoom('off')`, depending on what you need

Comment: @EitanT, it can be used in either way, both of the syntaxes are valid.

Comment: @Andrey Apparently, on earlier versions of MATLAB (like mine) your syntax doesn't work...

Comment: @EitanT, that is interesting, what is your version? (Also, I had a mistake - that is rotate3d, not rotate. Thanks for pointing that out)

Comment: @Andrey I'm running MATLAB R2009a, but I was using the wrong syntax too (`rotate` instead of `rotate3d`). Anyway, it works indeed.